# SecurityNegotiationException on SOAP WSDL api call in .NET core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, soap, wsdl

I have a .NET core API that calls an external SOAP WSDL.

The problem that i'm facing is that there seems to be some kind of problem with the SSL certificate:

This is the full error (without the stacktrace):

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'api.address.xyz'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

A bit more details:

I used the WFC Web Service service reference tool from Visual Studio 2022 to create the connected service.

I'm totally new to .NET core.

I'm using Google Cloud Run.

The problem seems to present itself only when the application is deployed on Cloud Run.

**What i tried:**

The first thing that came to mind was installing the root and intermediate CA certificate on the server, but on Cloud Run it seems to be impossible, or at least i can't find how to do it.

I tried telling the app to accept whatever certificate it gets using this code in `Program.cs`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT") ?? "8080";
            var url = $"http://0.0.0.0:{port}";

            //var url = "http://localhost:5001";

            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {
                  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls(url).ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                  {
                      o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(opts =>
                      {
                          opts.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                          opts.AllowAnyClientCertificate();

                      });
                  });
              });
        }
```

But it does not work.

I also tried updating all possible NuGet packages that i installed and recreating the connected service but nothing.

I think i'm missing the point.

Comment: If you are using SSL/ TLS than you should be using HTTPS (not HTTP).  Also SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete.  You should be using TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  Best way of checking what is happening is to use Wireshark and check the TLS blocks.  You should be using TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  There is a certificate block sent from server to client.  The certificate block contains the names of the certificates that can be used.  Client looks up the names in the users certificate stores to find matching certificate.  You need to check in wireshark the names of the certificates and if one is in the stores.

Comment: @jdweng That was indeed the problem. The WSDL was using TLS 1.2 and i was using TLS 1.0. Still i don't know how enable TLS 1.2 on Google cloud run, i switched to kubernetes and now it works fine

Comment: Adding static method at beginning of code usually solves issueon Core 3.1 : System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand where to add the code. I tried on program.cs and startup.cs but to no avail

Comment: The code can be any place before the request is made.  Use sniffer to see what version of TLS is being used.  Compare working an non working to see what version of TLS is being used.  The encryption mode in the certificate also has to work in both client and server.  And the certificate has to be loaded in the client.  There are too many possibilities right now to give an answer. Need more data.  VS 2022 should be using the operating system for TLS as default.  So issue could be the operating system is not supporting the encryption mode of certificate.  But it is too early determine cause.